# Search for keyword from prompt in Excel then create new tab with summary

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with many sheets (tabs).  I wanted to create a script in excel, such that when you hit run, a prompt comes up asking for "Text to search for", then after inputting the text, "failed" for example, the script then searches every sheet.  Then a summary sheet is created that contains the rows of the cells from the various tabs from the key text search.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which bit of your code is causing problems?

Comment: *Thanks for your help* - You have not actually asked for any help. I don't even see any question. Nor any code. Nor any errors. Reading [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing an example will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, paste this on a regular module,

```
    Private Sub FindAndPasteToReport()

' Declare variables we will use to loop through each worksheet
Dim eWs As Worksheet
Dim rFound As Range

' Declare variables to check if we are done looping through the worksheet
Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim rFirstCell As Range

' Declare and prepare the variable to hold the string we are looking for
Dim strLookFor As String
strLookFor = InputBox("Text to Search for")
If Len(Trim(strLookFor)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

' Declare and prepare variables used when creating the report
Dim rCellwsReport As Range
Dim wsReport As Worksheet

Set wsReport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("receiver")  '<~ you need to declare the sheet that will receive the report.
With wsReport
  Set rCellwsReport = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 2)
  rCellwsReport.Value = strLookFor
  Set rCellwsReport = rCellwsReport.Offset(1, 0)
End With

On Error Resume Next                            '<~ skip all errors encountered

' Start looping through this workbook
For Each eWs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If eWs.Name = wsReport.Name Then GoTo NextSheet '<~ skip if we are checking the report sheet
  With eWs.UsedRange
    ' Set the lastcell. So we can start the search from the bottom.
    Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count)

    ' Initial search for the string.
    Set rFound = .Find(what:=strLookFor, after:=rLastCell)
  End With
  If Not rFound Is Nothing Then                 '<~ if we found something then?

    ' Set it as the first find.
    Set rFirstCell = rFound

    ' Write its details to the report through this small sub.
    WriteDetails rCellwsReport, rFound
  End If
  Do
    ' Continue looking for more matches
    Set rFound = eWs.UsedRange.Find(what:=strLookFor, after:=rFound)
    ' Checks and exits the loop if the current cell is the same as the 1st cell
    If rFound.Address = rFirstCell.Address Then Exit Do
    ' If there are matches, write them down the report sheet.
    WriteDetails rCellwsReport, rFound
  Loop Until rFound.Address = rFirstCell.Address '<~ loop through until the current cell is the first cell
NextSheet:
Next

End Sub
```

along with this code.

```
Private Sub WriteDetails(ByRef rReceiver As Range, ByRef rDonor As Range)
  rReceiver.Value = rDonor.Parent.Name
  rReceiver.Offset(, 1).Value = rDonor.Address
  Set rReceiver = rReceiver.Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```

Now, this will not create a report instead, you need to initially create a worksheet that will receive all the texts. You need to update the line `Set wsReport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("receiver")` to your needs.

Comment: Hello,  sincerest thanks for your code.  I ran your code but was getting the cells to be repeating in the new tab that was created.   That is, the same cell number will show up twice in the output.  Also, how to add the row data itself in the next column of the outputs?  I sincerely appreciate your time and help!