# Search for keyword from prompt in Excel then create new tab with summary part 2

Tags: excel, find, vba

This question is building of the code developed by [Romcel Geluz found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44191554/search-for-keyword-from-prompt-in-excel-then-create-new-tab-with-summary)

- The attached code somehow creates duplicate entries in the newly created sheet with the found search text.  How to have each found row entry from each sheet to appear just once when the keyword is found?
- How to also append the found row columns to the created sheet, like this:

[image]

- How to name the newly created sheet, "Summary" and placed as the first sheet?

The original data in the sheets look like this:

[image]

Thanks for your help and time.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub FindAndCreateReport()

' Declare variables we will use to loop through each worksheet
Dim eWs As Worksheet
Dim rFound As Range

' Declare variables to check if we are done looping through the worksheet
Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim rFirstCell As Range

' Declare and prepare the variable to hold the string we are looking for
Dim strLookFor As String
strLookFor = InputBox("Text to Search for")
If Len(Trim(strLookFor)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

' Declare and prepare variables used when creating the report
Dim rCellwsReport As Range
Dim wsReport As Worksheet
Set wsReport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
Set rCellwsReport = wsReport.Cells(1, 1)

On Error Resume Next                            '<~ skip all errors encountered

' Start looping through this workbook
For Each eWs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If eWs.Name = wsReport.Name Then GoTo NextSheet '<~ skip if we are checking the report sheet
  With eWs.UsedRange
    ' Set the lastcell. So we can start the search from the bottom.
    Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count)

    ' Initial search for the string.
    Set rFound = .Find(what:=strLookFor, after:=rLastCell)
  End With
  If Not rFound Is Nothing Then                 '<~ if we found something then?

    ' Set it as the first find.
    Set rFirstCell = rFound

    ' Write its details to the report through this small sub.
    WriteDetails rCellwsReport, rFound
  End If
  Do
    ' Continue looking for more matches
    Set rFound = eWs.UsedRange.Find(what:=strLookFor, after:=rFound)
    ' If there are matches, write them down the report sheet.
    WriteDetails rCellwsReport, rFound

  Loop Until rFound.Address = rFirstCell.Address '<~ loop through until the current cell is the first cell
NextSheet:
Next

End Sub

Private Sub WriteDetails(ByRef rReceiver As Range, ByRef rDonor As Range)
  rReceiver.Value = rDonor.Parent.Name
  rReceiver.Offset(, 1).Value = rDonor.Address
  Set rReceiver = rReceiver.Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to have each found row entry from each sheet to appear just once when the keyword is found?

by starting the next search at the next row in the loop `Do ... Loop Until rFound.Address = rFirstCell.Address`

> How to also append the found row columns to the created sheet, like this:

by assigning the values to the current row starting from column `C`, as in the code below

> How to name the newly created sheet, "Summary" and placed as the first sheet?

by using the `before` parameter and the `.Name` property.

```
Set wsReport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(before:= ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1))
wsRTeport.Name = "Summary"
```

You will find more details in the highlighted sections of the modified code below. As an aside, I removed the `rLastCell` and the searching from the last cell, it doesn't make sense in the code. The `rFirstCell` can also be removed once you confirm that these modifications are what you are looking for.

```
Private Sub FindAndCreateReport()
  ' Declare variables we will use to loop through each worksheet
  Dim eWs As Worksheet, rFound As Range, rFirstCell As Range

  ' Declare and prepare the variable to hold the string we are looking for
  Dim strLookFor As String
  strLookFor = InputBox("Text to Search for")
  If Len(Trim(strLookFor)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  ' Create the report sheet at first position then name it "Summary"
  Dim wsReport As Worksheet, rCellwsReport As Range
  Set wsReport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1))
  wsReport.name = "Summary"
  Set rCellwsReport = wsReport.Cells(1, 1)
  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

  'On Error Resume Next               '<-- Probably not necessary

  ' Start looping through this workbook
  For Each eWs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If eWs.name = wsReport.name Then GoTo NextSheet '<~ skip report sheet
    Set rFound = eWs.UsedRange.Find(what:=strLookFor, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If rFound Is Nothing Then GoTo NextSheet
    Set rFirstCell = rFound
    Do
      WriteDetails rCellwsReport, rFound
      'Since we found a match on this row, we start our next search on next row
      Set rFound = eWs.UsedRange.Find(what:=strLookFor, _
        after:=eWs.Cells(rFound.row + 1, eWs.UsedRange.Column), LookIn:=xlValues)
    Loop Until rFound.Address = rFirstCell.Address '<~ loop to find other matches

NextSheet:
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub WriteDetails(ByRef rReceiver As Range, ByRef rDonor As Range)
  rReceiver.Value = rDonor.Parent.name
  rReceiver.Offset(, 1).Value = rDonor.Address

  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  ' Copy the row of the Donor to the receiver starting from column C.
  ' Since you want to preserve formats, we use the .Copy method
    rDonor.EntireRow.Resize(, 100).Copy rReceiver.Offset(, 2)
  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Set rReceiver = rReceiver.Offset(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: @A.S.H...Thank you!  You have help me immensely!  Still one issue though.  There may be more than one "text search" entry per sheet.  Is there a way to continue searching the sheet until all the 'search text' is found, then move on to the next sheet?  For example, page 2 may have the word "failed" in rows $F$2, $F$5, $F$33.  Also, can the formatting from the found row be kept (like cell color, etc.)?  THANK YOU so so much for your help and time!

Comment: I have updated the question with a picture of how the original data looks.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Joe you're welcome. As to finding more than one match from each sheet, of course it is possible but I thought you did not want that from your OP's sentence: *"How to have just the one entry when the keyword is found?"* What did you mean then?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  In the original code, there would be duplicate entries for the same "found" keyword.  That is, if a keyword is found in a sheet row, the same row will appear at least twice in the summary sheet.  My statement of to have just one entry means that each found row to appear just once.  Hope this clears it up.  I will make an edit to my original question to clarify that statement.  Also, can the formatting be transferred over also to the summary sheet.  Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: Sincerest thanks for all your time and help!  Exactly what was required!